# How to assign output of float expression to a variable in a shell script?

Tags: shell, echo

Here is my code

```
read a
read b
c=`echo $a / $b | bc`
echo "Answer is: " $c
```

I inputted values **10** and **3** to **a** and **b** respectively and i got the answer **3** in integer.
So i put scale as below

```
read a
read b
c=`scale=2;echo $a / $b | bc`
echo "Answer is: " $c
```

But it gives an error "command not found"

So how is it possible? See i want to store the answer in the variable, as i know to display float calculations using echo only.
I want the answer 3.33 stored in the variable $c.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use quotes around `scale=2` and your math expression:

```
a=10; b=3
c=$(echo "scale=2; $a / $b" | bc)    
echo "$c"

3.33
```